# How to print exact time of time based timezone in go?

Tags: go, time, timezone

Hi I want to convert this time
`2021-04-13 14:00:00 +0700 WIB`

to
`2021-04-13 21:00:00`

basically I need to print exact time based on some timezone location, I can't use this method

```
 time.ParseInLocation("02-Jan-2006 15:04:05", someTime.Format("02-Jan-2006 15:04:05"), location)
```

because it will return `yy-mm-dd- hh:mm:ss offset timezone`

Comment: could you please clarify *how* you want derive `2021-04-13 21:00:00` from `2021-04-13 14:00:00 +0700 WIB`? +7 means *ahead of UTC*, so I'd assume `2021-04-13 07:00:00 Z`?

Comment: To change the time zone of a Time value use [the In method](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.In). There's no need to format and then parse it.

Answer (score 4):

If you observe carefully, the time you get by parsing in location is time in that location. This is not like `2021-04-13 14:00:00 +0700 WIB` is `2021-04-13 21:00:00` but in fact, the time is `2021-04-13 14:00:00` in you given location. `+0700` only shows the offset, you do not have to update time using offset.

```
func main() {
    now, _ := time.Parse("02-01-2006 15:04:05 -0700", "07-05-2021 12:00:00 +0530")

    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("UTC")
    fmt.Printf("UTC Time:       %s\n", now.In(loc))

    loc, _ = time.LoadLocation("Europe/Berlin")
    fmt.Printf("Berlin Time:    %s\n", now.In(loc))

    loc, _ = time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
    fmt.Printf("New York Time:  %s\n", now.In(loc))

    loc, _ = time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kolkata")
    fmt.Printf("India Time:     %s\n", now.In(loc))

    loc, _ = time.LoadLocation("Asia/Singapore")
    fmt.Printf("Singapore Time: %s\n", now.In(loc))
}
```

The output of above code is:

```
UTC Time:       2021-05-07 06:30:00 +0000 UTC
Berlin Time:    2021-05-07 08:30:00 +0200 CEST
New York Time:  2021-05-07 02:30:00 -0400 EDT
India Time:     2021-05-07 12:00:00 +0530 IST
Singapore Time: 2021-05-07 14:30:00 +0800 +08
```

The time in evey location refers to that local time. The offset only shows the offset from GMT.

Comment: for UTC, you can use the shortcut `now.UTC()`

Comment: it is `time.Now().UTC()`

Comment: no, I mean the variable `now` in your code ^^ (kind of misleading variable name)

Comment: Ya, can do : D Thanks